# python psutil get numbers of cpu sockets

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu, psutil

it's possible to know numbers of sockets in my computer with python (and psutil ?)

for example with psutil i can to get numbers of core, but can i the number of sockets in mothercard ?

My computer have 2 sockets (and 2 xeon cpu)

Answer (score 2):

psutil does not return this kind of information (as far as I could tell from the documentation and the source code).

If you are on Linux you can get the information in python with the following code:

```
import subprocess
cpu_sockets =  int(subprocess.check_output('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "physical id" | sort -u | wc -l', shell=True))
```

Returns 1 on a single socket system (my Amazon server) and 2 on my Xeon workstation.

Answer (score -1):

psutils provides [cpu_count](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.cpu_count) function with parameters logical=True/False. logical=False returns the number of physical cores only.

```
psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
```

Comment: this is not my question, i ask numbers of sockets in the motherboard, not numbers of physical cpu

Comment: I dont think the socket count is provided by psutils. On linux you could parse the output of [lscpu](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lscpu)

Comment: I'm psutil author and I'm curious: what's your use case?
I always refrained from exposing this information because I couldn't see a use case.

Comment: ok, thnak's for your answer, i need number socket because i create program to check system configuration (in a server)

Comment: @Giampaolo Rodolà knowing number of sockets could potentially allow more efficient planning on NUMA vs not-Numa systems. Also licensing of many products such as Windows server, MS Sql Server, Oracle, Vmware and many more are dependent on number of sockets. Hope this gives enough reasons? ) So maybe, if not hard to add, you can include this feature in some upcoming release...

Comment: @GiampaoloRodolà A NUMA related issue is that sockets these days contain resources other than cpus, for example a data compression accelerator per socket.  A software process may schedule its tasks on a particular socket for performance optimization.